# Hosting Django app with Waitress

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to host a Django app on my Ubuntu VPS. I've got python, django, and waitress installed and the directories moved over.

I went to the Waitress site ( http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/ ) and they said to use it like this:

```
from waitress import serve
serve(wsgiapp, host='5.5.5.5', port=8080)
```

Do I put my app name in place of of 'wsiapp'? Do I need to run this in the top-level Django project directory?

Comment: try putting it in your **wsgi.py** and instead of wsiapp put **application**

Comment: I tried that and it started two server instances

Answer (score 27):

Tested with Django 1.9 and Waitress 0.9.0

You can use `waitress` with your django application by creating a script (e.g., `server.py`) in your django project root and importing the application variable from `wsgi.py` module:

**yourdjangoproject** project root structure

```
├── manage.py
├── server.py
├── yourdjangoproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
```

**wsgi.py** (*Updated **January 2021** w/ static serving*)

This is the default django code for `wsgi.py`:

```py
import os
    
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourdjangoproject.settings")
    
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

If you need static file serving, you can edit `wsgi.py` use something like [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) or [dj-static](https://github.com/heroku-python/dj-static) for static assets:

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourdjangoproject.settings")

"""
YOU ONLY NEED ONE OF THESE.
Choose middleware to serve static files. 
WhiteNoise seems to be the go-to but I've used dj-static 
successfully in many production applications.
"""

# If using WhiteNoise:
from whitenoise import WhiteNoise
application = WhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())

# If using dj-static:
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

**server.py**

```py
from waitress import serve
    
from yourdjangoproject.wsgi import application
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, port='8000')
```

#### Usage

Now you can run `$ python server.py`

Comment: Static files are not served, I am using django 2.2.6 and waitress 1.3.1 any idea what's the issue? I am using jinja tempate. 

Static works fine with python manage.py runserver

Comment: @IrfanAshraf I've updated this answer to include advice for serving static files

Comment: @IrfanAshraf you need to add the Whitenoise middleware in the Django settings

Comment: This works! Great job! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get it working by using a bash script instead of a python call. I made a script called 'startserver.sh' containing the following (replace yourprojectname with your project name obviously):

```
#!/bin/bash
waitress-serve --port=80 yourprojectname.wsgi:application
```

I put it in the top-level Django project directory.

Changed the permissions to execute by owner:

```
chmod 700 startserver.sh
```

Then I just execute the script on the server:

```
sudo ./startserver.sh
```

And that seemed to work just fine.

Comment: Great...Its very usefull, Do you have any idea to run waitress in daemonized mode.

Comment: Thanks.....I am using this in production as its light weight so would you please let me know how can i serve static files as well ?

Comment: @CrazyGeek from what I've read you should be serving static files through a much faster mechanism, e.g. Apache/Nginx if you're on VPS, or possibly S3 if you're using something like Heroku.